# Acumatica - Generic Inquiries: Links redirects to customized pages

Tags: acumatica

I created a page and graph that extends **ARPaymentEntry**. Now when I navigate to Receivables -> Payments and Applications -> then Hit “Add New Record” it goes to my page not the original page (AR302000).

Attached image is [my sitemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf9kB.png).

How do I configure Generic inquiry to open the specific page I want? And what am I missing why the built-in generic inquiry messes up when I extend a graph.
We decided not to use the built-in payments since will be adding custom computation and other business logic.

I am currently running Acumatica 2018 R1.

Thank You

Link to my [ARPaymentEntryExtension.cs](https://gist.github.com/linnaire/6ce749cc72c58be9b2d1543255f54f2b)

Link to my [Customized Page](https://gist.github.com/linnaire/f839cbe1b5577eb4c17e05b059729870)

Comment: I have run into issues in the past when more than one page uses the same graph. If you want a new page you should use a new graph. Maybe you want to inherit the graph vs a graph extension. Just a thought.

Comment: I see, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Generic Inquiry Screen]
on the `Generic Inquiry Screen`, Replace `ENTRY SCREEN SETTINGS` with your own page, so that when you open that `customized page`, the Generic Inquiry will be opened first, and Check `Enable New Record Creation` so that the `+` button will appear.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you sir.